# How to improve selection sort?

Tags: javascript, sorting

This is more of an academic/homework question?

Would it be better to change

```
if (index_outer !== index_min) {
    $P.swap(arr, index_outer, index_min);
}
```

to

```
$P.swap(arr, index_outer, index_min);
```

and always swap, as this is the special case when `index_outer` does have the smallest value?  It would be a swap that does nothing, but at the same time it would not break anything.  Because this does not happen often I suppose, it would reduce the amount of times an `if` check was used.

```
$P.swap = function (arr, i, j) {
    var temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
};

$P.selectionSort = function (arr) {
    var index_outer,
        index_inner,
        index_min,
        length = arr.length;
    for (index_outer = 0; index_outer < length; index_outer++) {
        index_min = index_outer;
        for (index_inner = index_outer + 1; index_inner < length; index_inner++) {
            if (arr[index_inner] < arr[index_min]) {
                index_min = index_inner;
            }
        }
        if (index_outer !== index_min) {
            $P.swap(arr, index_outer, index_min);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: If your code works as expected and your question is about improving it seems to fit better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this question belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com not here.

Comment: I'm not looking for feedback, it is a specific question.

Comment: You can setup a test on jsperf.com to see what is more time-consuming, the if or the swap. I bet it's the swap (as it involves a function call, and a variable declaration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it would always be a good idea. What if array was partially/fully sorted, you would be wasting a call to $P.swap().

As for improving selection sort try sorting the array from *both ends* simultaneously by taking **index_min** and **index_max**. Though number of comparisons would remain same, number of passes would decrease hence decreasing total run time.

Comment: ... wikipedia has many variants, I did not see this before I posted ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Variants